# REST filter=startswith not working when filtering using Id field

Tags: 2010, rest, listdata.svc

When filtering a text column like in built Title field using `startswith`, proper results are returned. Example:

```
http://aissp2013:111/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ChangeRules()?$filter=startswith(Title,'Ti')
```

However, `startswith` does not seem to work with inbuilt Id field. Following REST queries do not work:

```
http://aissp2013:111/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ChangeRules()?$filter=startswith(Id,1)
http://aissp2013:111/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ChangeRules()?$filter=startswith(Id,'1')
```

But querying the Id field using `eq` works:

```
http://aissp2013:111/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ChangeRules()?$filter=(Id eq 1)
```

Is there any way of making Id work with `startswith`?

Comment: The reason why it is not working because, startswith takes both parameter as string value and not an integer

Comment: Can you explain little more in detail?

Comment: the default syntax to use for startswith is" bool startswith(string p0, string p1)". ID is integer type, so you can only filter it using operators.

Comment: What is the source of this information?

Comment: http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/. Also since it takes both string parameters, you can try both values with inverted comas.not sure.just a suggestion

Comment: any solution you found?

Comment: No, I haven't found any solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `substringof` clause. Like this:

```
$filter=substringof(Id, '1')
```

More details on the following link: 
http://wiki.sensenet.com/index.php?title=OData_REST_API

Comment: No it doesn't work.

Comment: mmm maybe I wrong the param order substringof(Id, '1'), give a try in this way

Comment: Order doesn't make any difference.

Comment: That crap: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/51e79751-bfc4-4dc2-81f8-6961ee225e68/rest-filter-does-not-startwith-or-startswith-false?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: Also if you take a look on the msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798303.aspx

They wrote to use the startswith clause

Answer (score 1):

`startsWith` OData query option could **not** be applied to `ID` field since the function `startsWith` accepts field values of string type only (e.g. Text Field Type).

However you could use a different approach for query multiple items by ID as demonstrated below.

### How to query multiple items by ID via SharePoint REST

Option 1. Specify items explicitly using chained `and` and `or` operators.
Example: `/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Documents?$filter=(ID eq 1) or (ID eq 2) or (ID eq 3)`

Option 2. Specify items limit in a query using `top` operator.
Example: `/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Documents?$top=3&$orderby=ID`

Option 3. Specify the range using `lt`, `le`, `gt`, `ge` operators.
Example: `/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Documents?$filter=(ID ge 1) and (ID le 3)`

Comment: Thanks @Vadim, my problem is a bit different. I am actually working on auto complete functionality. So, I can't use any of the above methods. What I am looking for is some kind of workaround so that if a user types '15', then items with ID like '15', '151', '1523' .... etc show up.

Comment: @NadeemYousuf autocompelte on ID? That is a new one :)  I guess you are trying to do this Client-Side with the OOTB methods available, so have you tried csom?

Comment: Not necessarily ID, it can be any number column. I have a codeplex project for Autocomplete Lookup field. https://autocompletelookup.codeplex.com/. It uses REST to query the list. A user opened an issue that it doesn't work when lookup field is ID.

Answer (score 0):

Since ID is a longint, you can't. So, you need to put it to a string field. You can't use calculated values, so a SP workflow could do the trick.